# How do I stop my normals from spreading out under perturbation?

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, perturbation-theory

In many AI generative models you start with a so-called latent vector $\mathbf{z}$ of high dimension $d$ such that each $z_i \in \mathcal{N}(0,1)$. I'd like to randomly perturb this distribution in such a way the the perturbation is the same as $\mathbf{z}$ (e.g. a bunch of independent standard normals). When I try to do something like this

$$\mathbf{z} \rightarrow \mathbf{z}  + \Delta \mathbf{w}$$

Where $\Delta$ is a small number and $\mathbf{w}$ is another vector of independent standard normals. They start to spread out after enough iterations:

[image]

It looks like by new distribution is spreading out (albeit symmetrically). Two questions:

1. How do I adjust my update so that standard deviation stops spreading out? I assume it's a function of $\Delta$ and maybe the dimension $d$?
2. Is accounting for the standard deviation enough? Or are there higher moments that need to be adjusted as well? I've plotted the first 4 and they look OK ([code](https://gist.github.com/thoppe/09ddf2533c2ed5e9af6d329b64f64765) for reference), but I'd like to understand this from a mathematical perspective.

Comment: When you try to do "something like this" $\mathbf{z} \rightarrow \mathbf{z}  + \Delta \mathbf{w}$ and iterate these steps 100k times it is inevitable that the simulation spreads out.

Comment: @kurtG. Is there a way to adjust or rescale the new vector so that it stops from spreading out?

Comment: Technically there are many ways. The cheapest is obviously not to sum up the $\Delta\mathbf{w}$ and instead just draw a new one every time. The problem I have with the question is that it does not provide enough context/background to give a better recommendation that suits those AI needs.

Comment: For context, I'd like to see how the AI model responds to local changes of the latent vector. Thus I'd like to see a time series animation of the outputs w.r.t. a drift around it's expected input space. Sampling completely new vectors would lead to discontinuous movements in the output space. @kurtG.